# Construct year-month-day hour:min:sec from encoded string

Tags: excel, vba, hex

I have in a cell the following value `07DD0B190C3A00`

I know that:

```
07DD is the year      2013
0B   is the month     November
19   is the date      25th
OC   is the hour      Noon
3A   are the minutes  58
```

How can I translate this to `2013-11-25 12:58:00`

Answer (score 5):

Assumming the value is in A1, then this should work:

```
=HEX2DEC(LEFT(A1,4))&"-"&HEX2DEC(MID(A1,5,2))&"-"&HEX2DEC(MID(A1,7,2))&" "&HEX2DEC(MID(A1,9,2))&":"&HEX2DEC(MID(A1,11,2))&":"&HEX2DEC(MID(A1,13,2))
```

Comment: +1. Note though, you'll need the to load the Analysis ToolPak add-in if you're using excel 2003 or earlier. Otherwise you get a `#NAME` error

Comment: HEX2DEC is a built-in function in Excel 2007 and later versions - you shouldn't need Analysis ToolPak unless using Excel 2003 or earlier

Comment: @barryhoudini Good to know... I'm still on 2003 :(

Comment: @pnuts Good point.  It can be done of course by wrapping the `HEX2DEC(..)` calls with `TEXT(..,"00")`.  Makes it even uglier to read though...

Comment: You can also possibly have the same issue with hours or minutes if those are zero - one way round that is to use DATE/TIME functions and convert to a valid date/time in excel, i.e. `=DATE(HEX2DEC(LEFT(A1,4)),HEX2DEC(MID(A1,5,2)),HEX2DEC(MID(A1,7,2)))+TIME(HEX2DEC(MID(A1,9,2)),HEX2DEC(MID(A1,11,2)),HEX2DEC(MID(A1,13,2)))` - then you format as yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss